# row count on dataset different than row count on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm pretty certain this is a problem with my data binding, but I'm not for sure what the problem is exactly. Using mysql I'm getting rows showing up in my dataset, but no rows showing up in my datagridview after I do the binding.

```
conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=mydb;uid=user;password=pass");
conn.Open();

grid = new DataGridView();
grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
ds = new DataSet();

adpt = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from test limit 6;", conn);
adpt.Fill(ds);
Debug.WriteLine("data set rows found " + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count);

binding = new BindingSource();
binding.DataSource = ds;
grid.DataSource = binding;
Debug.WriteLine("data grid rows found " + grid.Rows.Count);

conn.Close();

Controls.Add(grid);
```

The debug printout for this is 6 and 0. Does anybody know where my problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do

```
grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Or.. If you want to using the BindingSource (say for filtering), set

```
binding.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```